# What happens to the .ru domains I purchased when the registrar blocks my account?

Tags: domain-registration

I bought 2 domains from Reg.ru and they blocked my account for using wrong passport number. I'm not able to login my account to fix my passport number.

Can I register those domain again from an another domain provider?

Comment: They _will_ or already have blocked your account for using a wrong passport number (ii.e., did you get an email indicating this)? Do you intend on supplying them with a valid passport number? If so, you should try to contact them [here](https://www.reg.ru/support/domains/) and explain that. Otherwise, unless they cancel the registration and delete the domain (unlikely), you'll have to wait for after the expiration date followed by a redemption period (around 90 days for most ICANN accredited registrars).

Comment: BTW, there are [many restrictions](https://www.godaddy.com/help/about-ru-domains-9200) on registering and managing [.ru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ru) domains, so unless you're specifically targeting Russia, perhaps you should think about registering a [gTLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain) with fewer restrictions.