# Where can I find the "codeword" for my reg.ru domain registration account?

Tags: domain-registration, domain-registrar

My Reg.ru account is suspended for logging in from different IP.

I have submitted a ticket to fix my account and they're asking for my 'codeword'. I've asked them what is codeword and they haven't replied me. I don't know how can I find the Codeword and submit it.

I have two domains registered in Reg.ru and they're very important. I need help figuring out how to get my reg.ru account back.

Comment: Related to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/105163/what-happens-to-the-ru-domains-i-purchased-when-the-registrar-blocks-my-account